# PHPDoc for fluent interface in subclass?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is there any why to make my IDE (actually PHPStorm) understand that:

```php
$student->setName('Marco');
```

Will return an instance of `Student`, without redefining `setName()` in the subclass (only for adding PHPDoc comments)?

```php
class Person
{
    private $name;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}

class Student extends Person { }
```

Comment: FYI: "funcion" above should be "function".  I tried to submit this as an edit, but the peer reviewers rejected it and said I should add this as a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return $this instead of person in your docblock

Answer (score 5):

you have to overwrite your method tag as comment like this

```
/**
 * @method Student setName($name)
 */
class Student extends Person { }
```

Comment: Ok this seems to work, but it would be a pain for many setters.

Comment: Do you have public methods in Student that you are wanting to access via the object returned by the fluent Person methods?  If not, and you really only need to be able to see all of Person's methods, then hopefully your IDE is already able to show them.  If, however, you do have public methods in Student that you did not already define in Person, perhaps for your API's sake you could declare them in Person but as abstract.  Like this, they are on the Person API (inherited by Student), documented only in Person, and still be visible to the IDE if the fluent methods all show @return Person.

Comment: The parameter list is not required

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I've found it helpful to use a combination approach.  My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA with PHP plug-in) complained that my fluent methods were returning `$this` when that value was used as a parameter to another method call later.  By changing the PHPDoc comment to this:

```php
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @return $this|Person
 */
```

The IDE was happier and the PHPDoc is more informative for the user.

Incidentally, by saying the method returns `$this` in the PHPDoc, it's a very good indication that the method is implementing a fluent interface.  Saying it returns `Person`, while technically accurate, doesn't necessarily indicate fluency.  For example, a method that creates a **new** `Person` object and returns it could also use that same annotation, but it wouldn't be fluent.